# generating many random matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to generate 100 different `5 by 5` random matrices using `matlab` in [0,1] with the following property: Assume that the required matrix is `A=[a_{ij}]` having the condition `a_{ih}+a_{hj}-a_{ij}-0.5=0` (Matrix `A` is the so-called Fuzzy Preference matrix (i.e.`a_{ji}=1-a_{ij} for all i,j`), and also consistent). But, I am stuck to write the matlab code. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Example of such matrix, but not consistent:

```
A=[.5 .5 .5 .8155 .5 .3423;...
   .5 .5 .6577 .8155 .5 .3423;...
   .5 .3423 .5 .88662 .75 .3423;...
   .1845 .8145 .1338 .5 .25 .25;...
   .5 .5 .25 .75 .5 .25;...
   .6577 .6577 .6577 .75 .75 .5]
```

Example of `3 by 3` consistent Fuzzy Preference matrix:

```
B=[.5 .2 .5;...
   .8 .5 .8;...
   .5 .2 .5]
```

Comment: So all of `h`, `i` and `j` can have any integer value in [1,5]? Can you give one example of a valid matrix? I can't quite see how this can hold for any `h`.

Comment: @Harry I put a matrix above. a_{ih}+a_{hj}-a_{ij}-0.5=0 means A is consistent.

Comment: Your example does not match the description:
`>> i=3;h=4;j=5;
>> A(i,h)+A(h,j)-A(i,j)-.5
ans = -0.11338` Result should be 0?

Comment: I'm pretty certain that the only matrix satisfying your condition for all combinations of `i`, `j`,  and `h` is the matrix with all entries 0.5.

Comment: @Daniel You are right. It's an example of inconsistent matrix. Thanks.

Comment: So can you give one example of a consistent matrix? (Apart from `0.5*ones(5,5)`, which isn't random).

Comment: @Userabc your matrix B is also inconsistent, `B(1,3)+B(3,1)-B(1,1)=0.5+0.2-0.5=0.2`. `B=[.5 .2 .5; .8 .5 .8; .5 .2 .5]` does work though.

Comment: @David Edited now.

Comment: @Harry it turns out there are infinitely many solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this question we need to find solutions to a system of linear equations. The unknowns are the matrix entries, so for an NxN matrix there will be N^2 unknowns. There are N^3 equations since there is an equation for each combination of `i`, `j`, and `h`. This is an overdetermined system, but is consistent, it's easy to see that the constant matrix with all entries 0.5 is a solution.

The system of equations can be written in matrix form, with matrix M defined as follows:

```
N = 5; % size of resulting matrix
M = zeros(N^3,N^2); % ar = size of matrix A

t = 0;
for i = 1:N
    for j = 1:N
        for h = 1:N
            t = t+1;
            M(t,(i-1)*N+h) = M(t,(i-1)*N+h)+1;
            M(t,(h-1)*N+j) = M(t,(h-1)*N+j)+1;
            M(t,(i-1)*N+j) = M(t,(i-1)*N+j)-1;
        end
    end
end
```

The right hand side is a vector of N^3 0.5's. The rank of the matrix appears to be N^2-N+1 (I think this is because the main diagonal of the result must be filled with 0.5, so there are really only N^2-N unknowns). The rank of the augmented system is the same, so we do have an infinite number of solutions, spanning an N-1 dimensional space.

So we can find the solutions as the sum of the vector of 0.5's plus any element of the null space of the matrix.

```
a = 0.5*ones(N^2,1) % solution to non-homogenous equation
nullspace = null(M) % columns form a basis for the null space
```

So we can now generate as many solutions as we like by adding multiples of the basis vectors of the null space to `a`,

```
s = a+sum(rand(1,N-1).*nullspace,2) % always a solution
```

The final problem is to sample uniformly from this null space while requiring the all the entries stay within `[0,1]`.

I think it's hard even to say what uniform sampling over this space is, but at least I can generate random elements by the following:

```
% first check the size of the largest element
% we can't addd/subtract more than 0.5to the homogeneous solution
for p = 1:size(nullspace,2)
    mn(p) = 0.5/max(abs(nullspace(:,p)));
end

c = 0;
mat = {};
while c<5 % generate 5 matrices
    % a solution is the homogeneous part 0.5*ones(N) plus
    % some element of the nullspace sum(rand(1,size(n,2)).*mn.* nullspace,2)
    % reshaped to be a square matrix
    newM = 0.5*ones(N)+reshape(sum((2*rand(1,size(nullspace,2))-1).*mn.* nullspace,2),N,N)

    % make sure the entries are all in [0,1]
    if all(newM(:)>=0) && all(newM(:)<=1)
        c = c+1;
        mat{c} = newM;
    end
end
% mat is a cell array of 5 matrices satisfying the condition
```

I don't have much idea about the distribution of the resulting matrices.

Comment: @DavidThanks. But, still newM returns negative values (out of [0,1]) . I am still not satisfied with the code.

Comment: `NewM` is not the final result, the final results are in `mat` (after the out-of-bounds checks).

Comment: Now it seems working when I write  mat{:} on the window command.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Just be aware that the final matrices, although random, are probably not uniformly distributed (as in the off-diagonal entries are not uniform). I did a bit of testing and the values do seem fairly well spread, but I don't know anything precise or quantitative.